# Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65 - react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I have a RN project, it runs fine in android but it is giving problems in iOS. I've used react-native-firebase in it. Is it the issue generated by firebase?

What didn’t work:
-Used legacy setting in Xcode that didn’t solve the issue.
-ran the project from xcode

if I run react-native run-ios, it is giving following error:

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited 
with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with 
Xcode.app, by opening qfo.xcworkspace
```

If I ran the project from xcode, build error is in the image:

Inside RNFirebaseInstanceId.m file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`#endif` is missing ?

Please check import has following syntax

```
#if __has_include("myinclude.h")
# include "myinclude.h"
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by:

1. entering a new folder,
2. recreating the react native package(with same name) react-native init app-name,
3. deleting the old(current failing) ios folder(move it if you want to save it),
4. adding the newly made ios folder to the main(original) app folder,
5. running react-native link (to relink all of the ios pod files etc) and now my app works on both ios and android.

Hope this can help someone in the future.